# NumberFormat doesn't work as a thousand separator for system locale?

Tags: android, locale, number-formatting

```
// above onCreate
private DecimalFormat decimalFormat =(DecimalFormat) 
NumberFormat.getInstance();

// inside my textWatcher

String[] splitted = originalString.split("((?<=[-+x÷])|(?=[-+.x÷]))");

                StringBuilder formatted = new StringBuilder();

                for (String word : splitted) {
                    try {
                        BigInteger num = new BigInteger(word);
                        formatted.append(decimalFormat.format(num));

                    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                        formatted.append(word);
                    }
                }
```

I have taken a number as a string variable and wanted to show with thousand separator like 2345678 as 23,45,678 when i am using in Nepali language. Badly the code works like this २,३४५,६७८ for 2345678.

Amazingly this works for Hindi Language as a system locale and can show 23,45,678. Why not for Nepali Language ??

Comment: According to this link, what wrong? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numbers_in_Nepali_language

Comment: There is a mistake in placing commas. I want to show Numbers [0-9], with commas like 23,45,678 when user is in Nepali Locale.

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
<NumberFormat thousandSeperator="." decimalSeperator="," onKeyDown = {(e) => 
{
const {key, target} = e;
const {selectionStart, value} = target;
if (key === '.') {
 e.preventDefault();
 target.value = `${value.substr(0, 
 selectionStart)},${value.substr(selectionStart, value.length)}`; 
  }
 }}/>
```

Comment: Is that Javascript?